# Internet Explorer 8 switches to compatability view after posting a comment

Tags: bug, compatibility

This just started happening recently:

After posting a comment, Internet Explorer 8 refreshes and displays SU (or any other SE site) in compatibility view:

[image: IE8 Compatibility View]

When viewing in compatibility view, the tag formatting is broken:

[image: Tag formatting broken in Compatibility View]

Any idea why this is happening? Is it just another stupid Internet Explorer bug?

Comment: We've had reports of this before, but I haven't been able to reproduce it.

Comment: Does this also happen with a newly created user account on your computer?

Comment: @balpha it seems to only happen when I submit the comment by pressing 'Enter'

Comment: Yep @NateKoppenhaver, that's what the other report said as well. I hadn't tried with real IE8 yet (just IE9 in IE8 mode), but I couldn't reproduce there; but even with a real IE8 we can't get this to happen. Very weird.

Comment: @DanielBeck StackExchange seems to be having trouble making a new account, so I can't test that currently

Comment: No,I meant  computer account.

Comment: @DanielBeck I'm unable to test that on this machine. When I get my [other computer](http://superuser.com/questions/360563/hard-disk-whistles-with-high-access-when-nothing-is-running) running again, I'll test to see if it happens on that one too

Comment: [too localized + being tracked on Meta.SO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114602/133693)

Answer (score 0):

I started having [this problem](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2073/compatibility-view-problem-with-xp-ie8) last September (IE8 under XP). I uninstalled several major software components - applications, device drivers, fonts, etc. (then re-installed most from scratch), after which the problem went away for some months, but reappeared just before Xmas.

This time I just didn't have the energy to go through all that uninstall/reinstall stuff - I never knew which component was critical, and obviously it was likely to fail again later. I switched to Google Chrome - within 1/2 hour I was finding Chrome just as easy to use (and **much** faster) After a day or so I was fully up to speed with Chrome, and I can't believe I put up with IE8 for so long just to avoid learning a different (and vastly superior) user interface on my browser!

TL;DR: Dump IE8 and switch to [Chrome](https://www.google.com/chrome/?installdataindex=nosearch&hl=en-GB&brand=CHMA&utm_campaign=en-GB&utm_source=en-GB-ha-emea-uk-bk&utm_medium=ha)! You won't regret it!

Comment: Actually, I've already switched - to Firefox. I have Chrome running on my Linux box and both Chrome and Firefox leave IE8 in the dust speed-wise, and they support the new web standards too (HTML5 and CSS3)

Comment: Many users don't have this option due to corporate policy. @NateKoppenhaver Consider unaccepting this answer, so it won't get ignored by the developers. It's not actually solved, you simply circumvented it/gave up for yourself.

Comment: @Daniel Beck: I understand your point, but for many people with this problem, my approach might well be the best "answer" - so I stand by the fact that I posted it as such, rather than just as a comment. And IMHO if you're working somewhere with a "corporate policy" requiring you to stick with effectively "unsupported" Windows XP + IE8, the *only* answer is to look for another job anyway.

Comment: I don't have anything against your answer. It's a perfectly acceptable solution from a user's POV, if you have the choice. But it remains a workaround and the site designers should fix it. IE9 was released less than a year ago. It's as obsolete as Firefox 3.6, and both still have tons of users. "Closing" this topic by having an accepted solution simply sends the wrong signals to the powers that be.

Comment: And have Google spy on all your websites and sell your passwords to third parties. No way.